# Avoid printing 'Exception ignored...' when using generator

Tags: python, json, generator

I'm using a generator in order to read file lines. The function is that:

```
def json_generator(f):
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        try:
            yield json.loads(line)
        except:
            pass
```

I call it as follows:

```
with open('file.json','r') as f:
    json_lines=(line for line in json_generator(f))
    for line in json_lines:
        ...
```

The function was created in order to avoid "jsonify" lines that are not "jsonifable". It works perfectly but, when script finishes I get the following error:

```
Exception ignored in: <generator object json_generator at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXX>
RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit
```

So, my question is: how can I avoid my script printing that? Better still... Is there any way to fix it and not to get this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stop catching the GeneratorExit; catch only the specific exception type you need to catch. (While you're at it, `file.read().splitlines()` unnecessarily reads the whole file into memory at once when you could just iterate over `file` directly, and wrapping `json_generator(f)` in a second generator is superfluous.)

Comment: @user2357112 at least link to other answers when you mark it as duplicate...

Comment: @Mehdi: It is impossible to mark a question as duplicate without linking a dupe target. See that "This question already has an answer here" banner?